# Property 'nodeName' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Tags: javascript, typescript

The following code is checking whether the user is in an input, textarea, or contenteditable. If that's the case `keys` should be emptied and the code should stop.

```
let keys: any[] = []

document.addEventListener('keypress', event => {
  if (event.key === ' ') return
  if (event.target === null) return // Should remove this?
  if (event.target.nodeName === 'INPUT' ||
    event.target.nodeName === 'TEXTAREA' ||
    event.target.isContentEditable) {
    keys = []
    return
  }
})

console.log(keys)
```

I'm getting this TypeScript error:

```
Property 'nodeName' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
Property 'nodeName' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
Property 'isContentEditable' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
```

Why is this and how to fix it?

Live code: https://codesandbox.io/s/cover-image-forked-7n8z7w?file=/src/index.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Event targets can include things like [xhr requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) and [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/message_event), so Typescript correctly won't let you assume it's a DOM node.

Once you realize that, it just becomes a matter of [narrowing the type via runtime checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) that are legible to the compiler.

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', (evt: KeyboardEvent) => {
  const { target } = evt;
  // Note e.g. XHR requests can be event targets, no nodeName
  if (target instanceof HTMLElement) {
    console.log(target.nodeName);
    if (target.isContentEditable) {
      // now we're good to process as e.g. textarea
    }
  }
});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/CYewxgrgtgpgdgFwHQENjAKIDd4IDICWAzgvDAE4AUA5ANYwCeADuTEUdQDQAElMWCAFzcA0owBGIFOUw5EASm4BeAHzcA3gChu3MCDgkN3BNIDmMBNwC+y7vwQBubdwD0L7gDkQpO0lNJuAA0ACQAlblYARwg2BCJdFDhucRg7OUsTcnM4njgQbjzgGA8UWGcCADNeTOzuAgMTODAYECrggBUAWTwMABsYWAUNZx09AxB+pF6QU0oaiyRC4tKYeScdHUrqswXiAGF9UkQMYAITcX7FLQ2NtwKQAHduB5hqVm5TEBBgJBHrZysmisa00miAA)

Answer (score 9):

`EventTarget` is not guarantied to be an `HTMLElement` or even a `Node`

You may replace your second condition with

```js
if (!(event.target instanceof HTMLElement)) return;
```